# Data entry into different tabs based on combo box VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, data-entry

i am trying to insert data into different tabs of an excel file via a combo box in VBA. I have got the tabs named ByteDance and Zapp. What I want is that if I select ByteDance in the combo box of the userform, the data that I insert will be in the ByteDance tab. The data however does not come from a database and needs to be filled in manually via data entry.

I have got a combo box named CompanyName and have managed to include the list of company names as shown. The list of company names is in the tab called "Names". As for the userform, it is named as "insertfundinground"

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  'Combobox listing
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Names")
  
  lastrow = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
  CompanyName.List = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value
  
End Sub
```

My userform looks something like this
[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QsyY.png)

So if I were to select ByteDance, the data that needs to be filled in manually will go to the ByteDance tab of my excel file. However, when I tried to do so, the data was not filled into the ByteDance tab although there were no error prompts. My code is as follows

```
Sub EnterInput()
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  
  Select Case CompanyName
    
   Case "ByteDance"
      lastrow = wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
      wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.DateInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("B" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.DealTypeInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("C" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.RaisedInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("D" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.PostMoneyInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("ByteDance").Range("E" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.InvestorsInput.Value
      
    
    
    Case "Zapp"
      lastrow = wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
      wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.DateInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("B" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.DealTypeInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("C" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.RaisedInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("D" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.PostMoneyInput.Value
      wb.Sheets("Zapp").Range("E" & lastrow + 1) = insertfundinground.InvestorsInput.Value
      
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Enter_Click()
  Dim msgValue As VbMsgBoxResult
  
  msgValue = MsgBox("Do you want to save the data?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirmation")
  
  If msgValue = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Call EnterInput
  End If
  
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Dim wb As ThisWorkbook` to

```vb
  Dim wb as Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

or alternative using With

```vb
Option Explict
Sub EnterInput()

    Dim ar, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    ar = Array("Date", "DealType", "Raised", "PostMoney", "Investors")
  
    Select Case CompanyName
        Case "ByteDance", "Zapp"
        
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(CompanyName))
                lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                    .Range("A" & lastrow).Offset(, i) = Me.Controls(ar(i) & "Input").Value
                Next
            End With

        Case Else
            MsgBox "'" & CompanyName & "' not valid", vbExclamation
   
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help however it didnt work

Comment: @Justin When you pressed the button did you get the  ""Do you want to save the data?" message ? I have updated code to check for valid combobox selection.